# Integrate WordPress in Java Platform for the SEO

Tags: seo, wordpress, java

I have a platform developed in JSF (Java) and a blog that was stored in Blogger. What I've done it is install Apache on my own server where Tomcat is installed, it install WordPress on Apache and it make migration Blogger . I have done this because I was told that a blog is an important SEO tool, and being in Blogger it was not contant to better position my platform made in JSF, it was best to unify.

My question is, as I can do to make my blog WordPress SEO, that it is in the same server that my JSF platform, but running on different containers (Apache and Tomcat), would count for my platform JSF SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly integrate WordPress and JSF on the same server, but it takes some Apache configuration.   Typically PHP webapps (like WordPress) run directly through Apache where as Java webapps require a secondary server such as Tomcat.

To run both at the same time, you would reserve a URL for the blog.  That url could be either a subdomain (blog.example.com) or a subdirectory (example.com/blog).   You would then configure Apache not to contact your backend Tomcat server for the blog.   How you exclude that URL depends on whether you choose subdomain or subdirectory, and what connection technology you use (mod_proxy vs mod_jk.)

A blog can certainly help your SEO if you write good content for it.   The technical details of how you host your blog matter less.   As long as your blog is well-integrated to your website (lots of links and navigation,) then your website should get the SEO benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your reply has helped me to evaluate my options. Thank you.